# BusyBox ps etime format is not as documented: 9h25

Tags: ps, busybox, alpine-linux

I've been using `ps -o etime,cputime` in a script to monitor spikes in CPU usage but when the server has been running for a while, the time is no shown in the widely documented format `[DD-]hh:mm:ss`, but is formatted as something like `9h35`.

How do I get it to stay in the expected format?

(I'm using alpine linux)

Answer (score 1):

Turns out there is no way to override this behaviour.

Looking at the [source code](https://git.busybox.net/busybox/tree/procps/ps.c#n313) for ps BusyBox it ignores the standard format and returns one of 4 formats

```
mm:ss for processes running less than 1 hour
HHhMM for processes running between 1 hour and 1 day
DDdHH for processes running between 1 and 100 days
DD for processes running more than 100 days
```

The code supports no overrides for this behaviour :-(

Answer (score 0):

You could actually override BusyBox ps with GNU ps by installing the [`procps`](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/v3.13/main/x86_64/procps) package:

```
apk add procps
```

When installed, the `/bin/ps` Busybox symlink is replaced with the the GNU `ps` binary. GNU ps should provide the familiar functionality and format.